# how to detect whether i am in incognito mode in google chrome extension application?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
function test(){
alert(chrome.extension.inIncognitoContext);
if(chrome.extension.inIncognitoContext){
   chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true},function(tabs){
      alert(tabs[0].url);
    });
}
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var link = document.getElementById('link');
   // onClick's logic below:
    link.addEventListener('click', function() {
    test();
  });
});
```

this is my .js file for the chrome extension application where i am calling the test() function on clicking a button in the extension(below is the html code of the extension). In both incognito mode and default chrome it is alerting as false. I have a seen in another reference to use the **boolean variable chrome.extension.inIncognitoContext to check this**. Am I wrong ,are is there  any problem with the code

```
<!doctype html>
<!--
This page is shown when the extension button is clicked, because the
"browser_action" field in manifest.json contains the "default_popup" key with
value "popup.html".
-->
<html>
<head>
<title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
<style>
  body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
  }
  #status {
    /* avoid an excessively wide status text */
    white-space: pre;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 400px;
  }
</style>

<!--
  - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
  - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
  -
  - [1]: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy
 -->
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id= "link" onclick="test()">store the page</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ Mr Xan   my question is not how to call a function on button click, but to find out whether i am in incognto mode or not. Yes Mr Apsillers is correct

Comment: @apsillers @Murali Mea culpa; I saw the offending `onclick` and did not read thoroughly. Reversing duplicate.

Comment: Do you have anything related to incognito in your manifest?

Comment: Could you also post your `manifest.json`? I am specifically interested in your `incognito` field.

Answer (score 5):

The [Chrome docs on `isIncognitoContext`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#property-inIncognitoContext) have this to say about the property:

> True for content scripts running inside incognito tabs, and for extension pages running inside an incognito process. The latter only applies to extensions with 'split' incognito_behavior.

Your code here is in a popup, which means it is an extension page. It is not a content script. According to the description above, extension pages only see a `true` value for `isIncognitoContext` if the manifest has the top-level property `"incognito": "split"`.

You probably have `"spanning"` or possibly nothing at all. According to [this page about incognito manifest options](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/incognito), `"spanning"` is the default:

> The default for extensions and Chrome apps is `"spanning"`, which means that it will run in a single shared process...